# A fast way to compute arrays avoiding If or Which

Tags: list-manipulation

I found out that if I have to calculate huge arrays with most of the elements being zero( let's say each row has 10000 elements and only 8 are non zero) and the non zero elements' positions being given by an If or a Which, the most straight forward way to go is:

```
Table[...,{i,1,nn},{j,list[i]}]
```

instead of

```
Table[If[MemberQ[list[i],j]==True,...],{i,1,nn},{j,1,nn}]
```

But the problem is that, list[i] does not fix the position in the array, but only the value, the positions being [1,Length[list[i]]]. Let us ilustrate this with an easy example:

Slow way:

```
A = Table[
Which[MemberQ[{1, 3, 5}, j] == True, 2*i + j, True, 0], {i, 1, 2}, {j,
 5}] // MatrixForm
(*(3    0   5   0   7
   5    0   7   0   9)*)
```

Fast way:

```
B=Table[2*i + j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, {1, 3, 5}}] // MatrixForm

(*(3    5   7
   5    7   9)*)
```

So, I would like to get the matrix A but doing it B way somehow.

(The condition for j, is an example, but in the real code is a rather complicated condition that varies with i.)

Does anybody see how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered `SparseArray`?

Comment: @xzczd yeah I tried many many things, as far as I am aware, you can not do this with SparseArrays, the most similar you can do with SparseArray is using Condition with SparseArrays, but that is slow.

Comment: By the way you never have to write `x == True` ;) instead you can write `x`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a complement to Anon's answer you can use pattern based rules in `SparseArray`, but depending on the pattern it may not be fast. (It will still have the memory advantage of a sparse array).  For example:

```
SparseArray[{i_, j:(1|3|5)} :> 2*i + j, {2, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 3 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 7 \\
 5 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 9
\end{array}
\right)$

If neither answer is applicable please try to clarify the question.

---

Alright, so your $j$ indexes are dependent on a function of the $i$ index.  You could do this with `Condition` as follows, but performance will be poor.  At the very least memoize the index function:

```
f[n_] := f[n] = Mod[Multinomial[Range@3, n], 5, 1]

SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; MemberQ[f@i, j] :> 2*i + j, {3, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 9 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11
\end{array}
\right)$

It would be better to build a position list as Anon described in a comment.  Here is a more complete example:

```
SparseArray[
  {##} -> 2 # + #2 & @@@ Join @@ Array[Thread@{#, f@#} &, 3]
] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 9 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11
\end{array}
\right)$

In a somewhat different style for use with listable inner functions (the `2*i + j` part):

```
is = Join @@ (ConstantArray[Range@3, 3]\[Transpose])
js = Join @@ Array[f, 3]

SparseArray[Thread[{is, js}] -> 2 is + js] // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}
>
> {2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5, 5}
> ```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 9 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: thanks. Let us say we have the following function that generates the previously mentioned list: Nx = 5;
Ny = 5;
N1[i_] := Module[{ix, iy, n1x, n2x, n3y, n4y},
   ix = Mod[i, Nx, 1];
   iy = Quotient[i, Nx, 1] + 1;
   If[ix + 1 > Nx, n1x = 1, n1x = ix + 1];
   If[ix - 1 < 1, n2x = Nx, n2x = ix - 1];
   If[iy + 1 > Ny, n3y = 1, n3y = iy + 1];
   If[iy - 1 < 1, n4y = Ny, n4y = iy - 1];
   {n1x + (iy - 1)*Nx, n2x + (iy - 1)*Nx, ix + (n3y - 1)*Nx, 
    ix + (n4y - 1)*Nx}];

Comment: Then, something similar to what you suggested but that is is not allowed would be: SparseArray[{i_, 
    j : (N1[i_][[1]] | N1[i_][[2]] | N1[i_][[3]] | N1[i_][[4]])} :> 
   2*i + j, {Nx*Ny, Nx*Ny}] // MatrixForm

Comment: So the point is, the condition for which j to choose, is given by function N1[i]

Comment: Could you do it using N1?

Comment: @Mencia OK, I see your problem.  Give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard uf I just spent some time trying to make nice data, but only now did I see these comments. I wonder if `MemberQ` uses a binary search in certain cases, as I think that would be fast. Anyway I have to go soon, so no timings for now. Also I feel a `SparseArray` is the way to go.

Comment: `SparseArray[SparseArray[list@# -> 2#+list@#, n]& /@ Range@n]` builds a separate sparse array for each row, then combines them. I like it because it's compact and easy to understand. However, it assumes that `list@#` is fast. If `list@#` is slow (or if for whatever reason you want to minimize the number of times it's evaluated) then `SparseArray[SparseArray[Thread[#2 -> 2#1+#2]&[#,list@#], n]& /@ Range@n]` takes the same approach but evaluates `list@#` only once per row.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , I have problems to use you r beautiful way to compute the SparseArray in this certain case where a has two indexes: a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};i = {1, 2};j = {1, 1};b = SparseArray[Thread[{i, j}] -> a[[i, j]]];SparseArray::rule1: The rule {{1,1},{2,1}}->{{1,1},{3,3}} is not of the form indices -> values. >>

Comment: whereas if a(in this case called c) has a single index, there is no problem: c = {1, 2, 3, 4};d = SparseArray[Thread[{i, j}] -> c[[i]]];

Comment: @Mencia to make sure I understand, what is the desired output for the first (failed) input?

Comment: How could I solve this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , b = {{1, 0}, {3, 0}}; is the desired output.

Comment: @Mencia I need to make breakfast but I'll return to this within the hour.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, haha great! Enjoy your breakfast!

Comment: @Mencia Okay.  I didn't re-read this thread so my apologies if I suggest something that makes no sense.  Your output can be produced with `i = {1, 2}; j = {1, 1}; SparseArray[Thread[{i, j}] -> {1, 3}, {2, 2}]`, so I suspect the problem is with `a[[i, j]]` which evaluates to `{{1, 1}, {3, 3}}` rather than `{1, 3}`.  Also I had to add explicit dimensions (`{2, 2}`).  If this helps, let me know; if not I'll refresh my memory of the context and try again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I gonna try refresh you. The point was to make lists(i and j) with desired points rather than using If or Which, when you have tones of zeros on your matrix. Now, for certain reasons, I need to do it like: a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};i = {1, 2};j = {1, 1};b = SparseArray[Thread[{i, j}] -> a[[i, j]]];, I want "b" to be the same as "a" in the desired positions, namely, in {1,1} and {2,1} and else 0. i and j are very long lists. Let me know if it is not clear.Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12558/discussion-between-mencia-and-mr-wizard)

Answer (score 5):

In example B you know the different indices, i.e. you know the positions of the elements. If you know the positions of the elements, you can use `SparseArray`:

```
SparseArray[Rule[#, 2 #[[1]] + #[[2]]] & /@ Tuples[{{1, 2}, {1, 3, 5}}]] // MatrixForm
(*(3    0   5   0   7
   5    0   7   0   9)*)
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer but, it does not really work for me because in my code it goes like ...{i,1,nn},{j,list[i]}], the list is i dependent, so it would be nice to have index i somewhere

Comment: @Mencia OK, you need a different code to generate your positions but the principle is still valid. You have all the information you need to calculate the positions. Perhaps something like `Flatten[Thread[{list[#], #}] & /@ Range[nn], 1]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a PackedArray, rather than a `SparseArray` object, the following is an option

```
cfu =
 Compile[
  {{list, _Integer, 1}, {nn, _Integer}}
  ,
  Block[
   {max = Max[list], len = Length[list], res}
   ,
   res = ConstantArray[0, {nn, max}];
   Do[
    If[
     list[[ll]] == j
     ,
     res[[i, j]] = 2*i + j
     ]
    ,
    {i, 1, nn},
    {j, 1, max},
    {ll, 1, len}
    ];
   res
   ]
  ]
```

example

```
cfu[{1, 3, 5}, 2] // MatrixForm
(*output*)
(*(3    0   5   0   7
   5    0   7   0   9)*)
```

The result is indeed a PackedArray

```
<<Developer`
PackedArrayQ@cfu[Range[1000], 3]
```

> True

Comment: Oh I should probably add CompilationTarget-> "C". I hope I can compare timings later

Comment: I await your timings.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm just simple-minded, but can't you just create a zero matrix:

```
s = SparseArray[{}, {2, 5}, 0]
```

Then fill in the non-zero ones as required:

```
Table[s[[i, j]] = 2 i + j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, {1, 3, 5}}]
```